# Caused by: org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: Spring Data Redis

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data-redis

I am developing code by taking reference from : https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=Just-Fun/spring-data-examples/spring-data-examples-master/jpa/query-by-example/src/test/java/example/springdata/jpa/querybyexample/UserRepositoryIntegrationTests.java.

User.java

```
@Data
@RedisHash("User")
public class User {

    private @Id Long id;
    @Indexed
    private String firstname; 
    @Indexed
    private String lastname;
    private Integer age;

    public User() {}

    public User(String firstname, String lastname, Integer age) {
        super();
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
public interface UserRepository extends QueryByExampleExecutor<User>, CrudRepository<User, String> {

}
```

**RedisExampleApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RedisExampleApplication implements CommandLineRunner{
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RedisExampleApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        userRepository.deleteAll();

        User skyler = userRepository.save(new User("Skyler", "Doe", 45));
        User walter = userRepository.save(new User("Walter", "White", 50));
        User flynn = userRepository.save(new User("Walter Jr. (Flynn)", "Kerr", 17));
        userRepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(skyler, walter, flynn));

        long count = userRepository.count(Example.of(new User(null, "White", null)));
        System.out.println("COUNT ? "+count);


        Example<User> example = Example.of(flynn, matching().//
                withIgnorePaths("firstname", "lastname"));

        Optional<User> findOne = userRepository.findOne(example);
        System.out.println("USER ? "+findOne);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:816) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:797) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.RedisExampleApplication.main(RedisExampleApplication.java:23) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1
    at org.springframework.data.redis.repository.support.QueryByExampleRedisExecutor.findOne(QueryByExampleRedisExecutor.java:107) ~[spring-data-redis-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.findOne(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.RedisExampleApplication.run(RedisExampleApplication.java:45) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:813) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably due to :

```
Optional<User> findOne = userRepository.findOne(example);
```

Here you are using `findOne` method, but it seems that you are getting more than one results. Thus, either use `find` method or modify your search condition which ensure that you will get a single result.

Comment: I think your understanding is wrong here. By the use of findOne method, spring-data assumes that you have only one record satisfying the condition(like when you search with a primary key). If in case you get more than one record, then you face such exceptions. 
Note: findOne method does not filter out a single record from your result set. It excpects that  your result set should have only one record

Comment: See that is what I am trying to explain you..findOne method expects that your result should have a single record, if it has more than one record, then you face this exception. Please go through the documentaion of findOne to be more clear

Comment: Then you need to share data as well 

Comment: Whic records are you getting when you use findAll